How to automate adding ip addresses to Suspicious objects in Trend Vision One
Hello in my company we have this incident " A network session Source [ ip ] matched an IoC.
Ips are checked in IpDb automatically but adding them to Suspicious objects in TRend is made by hand.
Do you guys know how to automate this ?
Honestly nothing has been done for now, we only turned on coupling to reduce the amount of incidents.
We are thinking about totaly stop giving a single F about this incident. But I want to know if there is a way to do it, currently I am checking thier APi.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
